# Exception: User-mode data execution prevention (DEP) violation at location when calling Rust FFI library function on x86 Windows and Linux

Tags: rust, ffi, rust-tokio

I'm using Rust to call a Rust-written FFI library function. The library function runs fine on macOS Pro with an M1 processor. However, when running on x86-based Windows and Linux virtual machines, I encounter an error whenever any method within the library function is called. The error message is as follows:

> Exception: Exception 0xc0000005 encountered at address 0x7fffd7609220: User-mode data execution prevention (DEP) violation at location

Problematic code repository: https://github.com/dingdaoyi/yanbing-edge

Code snippets:

Library function:

```rust
fn initialize(&mut self, device_list: Vec<Device>, sender: mpsc::Sender<PointEvent>, handle: Handle) -> Result<(), String> {
    ModbusTcpProtocol::init_log();
    println!("协议包含数据:{:?}", device_list);
    self.sender = Some(sender);
    self.device_list = device_list;
    self.handle = Some(handle);
    self.init_modbus();
    self.schedule_event();
    Ok(())
}
```

Main function invocation:

```rust
pub async fn load_protocol(
    &self,
    config: &ProtocolConfig,
    sender: mpsc::Sender<PointEvent>,
    device_list: Vec<Device>,
) -> Result<()> {
    // Load the protocol library
    let lib_path = Path::new(&self.lib_path);
    let protocol_path = lib_path.join(get_library_filename(&config.path));
    let lib = unsafe { Library::new(protocol_path) }?;

    // Get the create_protocol function symbol
    type CreateProtocolFn = extern "C" fn() -> *mut dyn Protocol;
    let constructor: Symbol<CreateProtocolFn> = unsafe { lib.get(b"create_protocol")? };

    // Call the function to obtain a raw pointer to the Protocol trait instance
    let boxed_raw = constructor();

    // Construct a Box from the raw pointer
    let mut protocol_box = unsafe { Box::from_raw(boxed_raw) };
    let protocol_box1 = unsafe { Box::from_raw(boxed_raw) };
    tokio::task::spawn(async move {
        let handle = tokio::runtime::Handle::current();
        protocol_box.initialize(device_list, sender, handle).unwrap();
    });
    self.add_protocol(config.id, protocol_box1)
}
```

I attempted to invoke a Rust FFI library function, which worked successfully on macOS M1. However, when running on x86-based Windows and Linux platforms, I encountered an issue where the functions were not being called and an exception error occurred.

Expected Result:

I expected the library functions to execute without any errors or exceptions.

Actual Result:

To my surprise, regardless of whether the library function contained complex business logic or simple print statements, the functions were not invoked and an exception error occurred with the message "Exception: User-mode data execution prevention (DEP) violation at location." This issue only manifested on x86-based Windows and Linux platforms, while it worked fine on macOS (M1 chip).